# How do I login to MS SQL server ? authentication

Tags: passwords, login, authentication, sql-server

I have no idea on how SQL works. I'm just trying to use a program that is using SQL Server.

I have SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

In my start menu I only see a list of programs in 2008. In the 2005, I only see Upgrade Advisor.

I installed a program and it's asking for my username and password for the server : localhost:8090. During the installation you can chose between Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication. The SQL Server authentication doesn't work so I'm using the windows authentication.

I tried admin and I get a password error. If I try mycomputername\myusername or myusername mycomputername\sqlexpress sa and I always get wrong username

Is there a way to create a user/password or reset? I tried going into SQL Server Management Studio but I have no idea where to go or how to write.

Should I just reinstall ?

Comment: Windows authentication uses the account you are logged on to Windows. SQL Server auth is ordinary login/password, not associated with Windows accounts. You can start SQL Server into single user-mode and reset your password from there / change authentication methods. But your issue is strange because 8090 is not default SQL Server port. Maybe this is not SQL Server but a web server instead? Try opening http://localhost:8090 on the browser and seeing what happens.

Comment: Their technical support changed password, this is unlikely to help any one in the future

Answer (score 3):

Passwords for SQL users and administrators are set while the SQL Server installation process takes place. Using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) you can access SQL Server on the same or other machine. To login, you should know the password, that SQL Server was installed with. The standard administrator is 'sa', not 'admin'. Also, if this is local machine, you should be able (if installation was made by local user/administrator) to login by Windows Authentication (with the same user, that the SQL Server was installed). There is no default password, but it can be empty. Try using 'sa' login with empty password or Windows Authentication. If this does not solve your login problem - try to find out what the password was=is. If this is not possible, you may need to reinstall SQL Server.

Comment: I tried reinstalling, and I chose Windows authentication and all options that doesn't require a password.  Still can't login with my other program that is using a DB.  I login SSMS and tried to give my account full access to stuff by checking all boxes.

Comment: To use Windows Auth. in other app, you may have to specify also the server name in username, eg. "\\comp_name\user_name". Or without first backslashes. Just the computer name given. User context should be specified and in that case context is the computers name.

Answer (score 0):

password was ****, the tech support finally answered and it was builtin the program that was using the database.  Wasn't in the Installation Guide :( .